# Way to check for null value in if condition

Tags: c#

I have the following line of code, which is giving me trouble of NPE

```
   ServeUrl = ((NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Servers")).Get(ment);
```

When I write this in the following way, I no longer get the NPE

```
  if (ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Servers") != null && ((NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Servers")).Get(ment) != null)
                            {
                                ServeUrl = ((NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Servers")).Get(ment);
                            }
```

Somwhow, the above thing does not look good to my eyes. How can I write this in a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd extract a temporary variable:

```
var section = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Servers");
if (section != null && section.Get(ment) != null)
{
    ...
}
```

Or even:

```
var section = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Servers");
if (section != null)
{
    var url = section.Get(ment);
    if (url != null)
    {
        ServeUrl = url;
    }
}
```

What would you want to do if `GetSection` returned null though? Can you *actually* keep going?

Comment: Just one thing to add, wouldn't be GetSection() as NameValueCollection be a bit safer? Depending if getSection can return something else than NameValueCollection, which would explain the cast.

Comment: @dowhilefor: It depends on what you mean by "safer". If it's an *error* (e.g. in configuration or programming) for `GetSection("Servers")` to return some other kind of object, then I'm absolutely fine with an exception. It feels like this is the kind of situation which should stop the system coming up, rather than trying to continue.

Answer (score 1):

1. `!=` means `not equal to` and `==` means `equal to`
2. If you can't use `NULL` you can use `""`

Apply the condition with logic and then even after it is not getting what you want then:

1. condition will be `false` and you also used `AND` logical operator

Answer (score 0):

I would have used this(FYI,i haven't tried this in compiler):

```
 if (ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Servers")?.Get(ment) is NameValueCollection nvc)
                        {
                            ServeUrl = nvc;
                        }
```